# how can I send selected rows(with checkbox ) of datagridview to datatable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want send the selected rpws of a datagridview to datatable
I should say that one of my datagridview's columns is checkbox
this is an image of what I want:

http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1378997861 "how??"

Comment: Is your datagridview databound?

Comment: It all depends whether the checkbox is bound to the actual data source or just a display element in the table... For the first case you just filter for the correct boolean in the datasource, the second you have to work with ui elements.

Comment: @Vlad My checkbox is bound to the actual data source. can u help me? I need ADO.net and C# codes for solve this problem...actualy I dont have any information to this algorithm ! if you can get me sample code for send selected rows of gridview to DataTable, i'll be so thankfullllllllll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
public DataTable GetDataTableFromDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
    {
        //// I assume you need all your columns.
        dataTable.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.CellType);
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        //// If the value of the column with the checkbox is true at this row, we add it
        if (row.Cells["checkbox column name"].Value == true)
        {
            object[] values = new object[dataGridView.Columns.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                values[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot..how can I bind this DataTable to an object of CrystalReportViewer in Form2 to print selected rows of DataGridView2 ?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, described here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1794269.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to send a collection of `DataGridViewRow` objects, here is how you should only get those which are checked:

```
var rows = yourDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => (bool)
    (row.Cells["name of checkbox column!"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value);
```

In case your `DataGridView` is databound, of course you should directly operate on the data isntead of juggling and casting around `DataGridViewCells`.

Same as above without LINQ:

```
var rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
    if((bool)(row.Cells["name of checkbox column!"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value)
        rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: `Rows` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` hence `Rows.Where` not possible, need `Cast` :(

Comment: @olydis thanks alot , but I dont have any information about LINQ that you've written those codes....can u rewrite with ADO ?

Comment: @olydis  thanks alot! but I asked another question about "Vlad's" answer ...I'l be so thankful if you can answer that